# Storage Array monitoring

Tags: monitoring

I am new to monitoring & managment world, would like to configure storage arrays for monitoring and management pupose. can any one help me to understand basics of configuring monitorig for storage arrays or point to the link where i will get information. i got some information that it can be done through maps or smp but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally storage arrays offer either SNMP or alertmail based monitoring, either directly from the array of via any centralised management machine. There's usually nothing too storage-specific about these methods but obviously the MIBs/messages will be storage specific.

Comment: Thanks Chopper, can you point me to any site where I can get informaion how this can be done using SNMP

Comment: Oh that depends on the array, if it's EMC their site will have details, same for HP, NetApp, Hitachi etc. There's a decent-enough SNMP explanation on wikipedia but that's not vendor or storage-specific.